# Android - how to slide screens, inside a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, slide

I've created an app, that has a main activity with a drawer menu so the user can click on some option and a fragment is open inside the activity.
What I'd like to do is to have several screens in one of the options and to navigate between them by tabs/slide the screen.
I saw an example of doing it inside one activity and with a fragment per 'sub-screen', my question is: how can I do it when I'm already 'inside' a fragment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Fragment`s can support having other `Fragment`s inside them.  The key to making this work is to remember to use `getChildFragmentManager()` to get the `Fragment`'s `FragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager()` which gets the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager`.

If you want to swipe between views, use a `ViewPager` inside your `Fragment` UI.  The `ViewPager` will use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to handle the `Fragment`s for display.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and post my results here.